# php read links rss

Tags: php, forms, url, rss

i was wondering, how would i go about setting up a php code such that when someone enters a url into a form i would like to extract the name of the webpage and a photograph similar to what happens in facebook when you put a link on someones wall, you get the title of the link and picture. 
Do i have to read an rss feed or what ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And no it has nothing to do with an RSS feed and to do it without a refresh, you need some AJAX, PHP cant do it. BTW it is not THAT simple.

Comment: You would have to parse the page, isolate any `img` elements in it, and display them. This is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662

Comment: what link you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rss feed are XML therefore you should be able to DOM or SAX in conjunction with Xpath to retrieve these informations by hand.

[Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html) provides an easy way to work with feeds (either RSS or Atom).

```
$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import('http://www.planet-php.net/rdf/');
$feed->getTitle();
```

Concerning the preview picture, I don't know any free and out of the box solution.

You can take a look at thumbshots.org which provides free thumbnails for websites which in DMOZ but requires a paying subscriptions for others.

You can also try http://www.guangmingsoft.net/htmlsnapshot/html2image.htm which is well know and available on Linux, but still not free.